# Mono for Android - OpenFileOutput - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, xamarin.android, streamwriter

I'm trying to call **OpenFileOutput()** function but I'm getting an ***IllegalArgumentException*** from the *StreamWriter* constructor.
The function is called within the method *LogFile()* of a regular class (not an *Activity* or *Service*) which shall be used afterwards by an *Activity*.

In order to compile the code, I passed to the method an extra Context as a parameter:

```
public void LogFile(string msg, Context _context)
{
   using (var f = new StreamWriter(
                  _context.OpenFileOutput(filename, FileCreationMode.Append | FileCreationMode.WorldReadable)
                ))
            {
               f.Write(msg);
            }
}// end LogFile().
```

This context parameter is previously handed over from the *Activity* to the method using the constructor the method's class:

```
LogClass flog = new LogClass(this.ApplicationContext);
```

Any suggestions of what could be missing ?

Comment: Have you found the problem yet?

Comment: Getting same problem here.